# SQL: help with sql joins

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Hi I have an app that has posts, tags, and a tag_ref link table. I want to query for posts that have a specific tag association.

The database structure is as follows:

**posts**

id

**tags_ref**

row_id

table

tag_id

**tags**

id

safe_tag

tag

My query basically goes if $safe_tag is not null then join tags_ref on post.id = tags_ref.row_id, join tags on tags_ref.tag_id = tags.id, where tags_ref.table = 'posts' and tags.safe_tag = 'food' and post.city_id = 2

Is this query correct? Am I using the correct type of join?

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
INNER JOIN `tags_ref` ON `posts`.`id` = `tags_ref`.`row_id`
INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags_ref`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`
WHERE `tags_ref`.`table` = 'posts'
AND `tags`.`safe_tag` = 'food'
AND `posts`.`city_id` = '2'
```

I'm getting odd results that have no tags associated at all.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you quoting all the table and column names? Did you mean to have the `city_id` constraint?

Comment: @Oded, it's a print out from codeigniter profiling feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only return results from the `posts` table, as opposed to *all* columns in the join tables. I have removed the `city_id` constraint that you haven't specified in your question text (and that *was* in your query):

```
SELECT P.*
FROM posts AS P
  INNER JOIN tags_ref AS TR ON P.id = TR.row_id
  INNER JOIN tags AS T ON TR.tag_id = T.id
WHERE TR.table = 'posts'
AND T.safe_tag = 'food'
```

I have also added table aliases and removed the quoting.

If you do not get any results, that would suggest to me that there are no posts with the `food`.

Comment: your query works, though I do want to have a city_id constraint. Each post has a city_id field which is not null. What is the different between your query and mine? I can't see anything apart from the alisases

Comment: @iamjonesy - No different, apart from the differenced noted above. However, if your `city_id` is an integer type, you should query it without the quotes: `AND P.city_id = 2`. If this still doesn't work, check your data.